# Trouble generating PDF's from dynamic content using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, client-side, jspdf

I'm having a problem generating PDF's.

Our client wants to generate PDF documents containing selected content from the data provided by the users of the site. I'm trying to use a client-side solution using javascript, jQuery and jsPDF but I'm having some troubles.

The content that can be displayed in the document are text, images, colors and others.

This is the rough screen of the document generator.
[image: Document Generator View]

The column on the left shows the selected content which can be displayed on the document. Each element has a button (the black area inside each one) which clones the full element using jQuery to the document container (the white box). Everything works fine and after cloning elements to the document container, I use the Export To PDF button to call a jQuery event to use the jsPDF library and generate the document. But this is where everything goes wrong.

[image: Content added to the document container]

If I click the Export button, the Save File dialog pops in and asks me to save or view the file. When I open that new PDF file, the document is full blank, it doesn't have any elements. BUT, if I didn't add any selected content to the document container, the saved PDF file shows the header content of the document, which is the default content of every file.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The javascript console doesn't show any error messages.

Each selected item has the class **grid__item**, the document container has the class **document-page**.

My code is the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-add-element-to-document', function () {
     $(this).parent().parent('.grid__item').clone().appendTo('.document-page');
} );
$('.js-export-to-pdf').on('click', function () {
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    pdf.addHTML( $('.document-page'), function () {
        var string = pdf.output( 'datauristring' );
    });
    if( typeof pdf !== 'undefined' ) {
        setTimeout( function () {
            pdf.save( 'travel-document.pdf' );
        }, 500);
    } else {
        alert(' Error on generating document ');
    }
});
```

Am I ignoring something else? Is there something that is breaking the content of my generated document? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

addHTML() is an asynchronous function. You will have to call "save" inside the callback you are passing.

As you have a lot of content, addHTML might not have been completed when you are calling save. That is the reason saved pdf is blank.

example -

```
pdf.addHTML($("#someDiv"), function(){
   //addHTML completed 
   pdf.save("test.pdf");
});
```